# Cancel file downloading on Single Page Application

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

I have been developing a SPA using angularjs, ui-router. Its basically an audio library. There is a listing page where the user clicks on the title of the audio and he is navigated to a SPA page where an audio player appears and the file starts streaming. The problem is that if the user navigates away from the audio player page, e.g. to "about us" page. The audio file keeps on downloading. This is undesirable as this could download multiple audio files in the background if the user keeps on browsing different pages and audio player pages.

Is there any way I can abort/cancel the file downloads when the user navigates away to some other page of the SPA?

Thanks

Comment: You have the abort/cancel logic and you are looking for a place you can add your code. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No I dont have the logic. I just want the App to cancel all the files being download when the user navigates away to another page of the SPA.